# How to install Debian package manager

Tags: linux, debian, installation, aptitude, dpkg

I have a testing platform which has minimal Linux on it. It is so lightweight that it lacks all distribution-specific features. The goal is to install `dpkg` and `apt-utils`, which I did, by extracting `.deb` archives to `rootfs`, creating an empty `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file, adding `APT::Cache-Limit "100000000";` to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, and of course, adding repositories manually to `/etc/atp/sources.list`. The problem is, which ever package I try to install `apt-get` claims it is not installable, and then lists conflicting dependencies. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your setup, what you've tried to install, and what dependencies it reports as conflicting?  Did you start with an existing, bare-bones, Debian-based distro on which you're trying to build, or did you create your platform by stripping away pieces from a distro?  Any chance your situation is that you're missing some basic functionality, like it's just a simple CLI, and what you want to install expects some GUI support?

Comment: It is an `IoT` device, I started with the factory firmware, the goal is to install `gcc` `make` and other development tools when and if needed. It has `bash` shell with core utilities, and I will not be needing any sort of GUI.

Comment: If the installed system is not Debian-minded, then I'm not sure you will be able to install apt-get at all, at least not without more than a little 'coaching'. Debian programs rely on having certain framework of directories, utility programs etc, which probably won't match yours. That framework differs from distro to distro. You might have slightly more success with Slackware, which is much more 'generic'

Comment: I too need to do this. If you found a solution, please share.